# How do I set a background image in OpenGL/GLFW?

Tags: opengl, c++, menu, glfw

I'm writing a simple 2D game with C++ and OpenGL/GLFW, and my current step is to create a menu. I finished with buttons, but I think it looks a little bit boring (with only 4 buttons and a black background).

[image]

I want to load an image (.jpg, .tga, .png, etc) to make a more beautiful menu, but I can't find out how. How can I do it?

Comment: How are you loading the button icons?

Answer (score 2):

After your glClear call you can render a full-screen quad with your texture (loaded like you would any other). You may want to disable writing to the depth buffer to avoid odd rendering issues.